# Is there a free Aztec code decoder/scanner for Linux?

Tags: gratis, linux

Is there a free Aztec code decoder/scanner for Linux?

Aztec Code is a type of 2D Matrix/barcode, like QR code. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aztec_Code

A scanner would analyze an image with a code (potentially acquiring it with a camera) and output the decoded content.

E.g. the output for this code

[image: Example Aztec code]

should be "This is an example Aztec symbol for Wikipedia."